# #<NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass> in Rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

- I'm using `spring rails s` to start my server.
- It's a Rails 6.0.0 application

Whenever accessing `localhost:3000` I'm see this error message:

```
2020-02-15 11:31:36 -0800: Rack app error handling request { GET /favicon.ico }
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass>
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.2.0/lib/rack/request.rb:623:in `reject_trusted_ip_addresses'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-2.2.0/lib/rack/request.rb:363:in `ip'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-mini-profiler-1.1.0/lib/mini_profiler/config.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in default'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-mini-profiler-1.1.0/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:87:in `user'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-mini-profiler-1.1.0/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:343:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:29:in `perform_request'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
/Users/amirsharif/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I didn't identify the root cause.

After updating rack to 2.2.2 this issue went away so I'm unblocked now.

I believe the source of the problem was that in @env within the rack request there was no HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header being sent.